# "the" meaning in "The willingness of a Wall Street investment bank to pay me hundreds..."

Tags: definite-article

> **The** willingness of a Wall Street investment bank to pay me hundreds of thousands of dollars to dispense investment advice to grown-ups remains a mystery to me to this day.—*The Big Short: Inside the Doomsday Machine* by Michael Lewis—

I've searched a meaning of "the" on Lexico Dictionary but I'm not sure what it supposedly mean. So I'm quoting possible meaning below that I think.

> 2.Used to point forward to a following qualifying or defining clause or phrase

Comment: It means the same thing it means anywhere else.  The investment bank could be willing to do many things, but we're specifically talking about their willingness to pay  Michael Short. It might help if you explained how you thought the sentence should be phrased.

Comment: Wait. I don't understand. You understand the entire rest of the sentence, but you do not understand "the"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The word "of" serves a lot of purposes in English, so you must consider it in context. The following are both correct:

> I would like **a liter** of water.
> **The density** of water is 997 kg/m³.

The difference is that **a liter** indicates one random part of all the water in the universe, while **the density** indicates a unique property of water.

We can imagine the same relationships for "a Wall Street investment bank." Once you imagine the existence of such a bank (that's what "a" does), you have *implied* the existence of all of its unique properties, real or hypothetical. And when the existence of a thing has been implied by the context, any mention of it can be considered a second mention, and "the" is appropriate. That is why all of the following are correct:

> the location of a Wall Street investment bank
> the height of a Wall Street investment bank
> the taste of a Wall Street investment bank

Similarly, "the willingness . . . to pay me" can be thought of (grammatically) as a unique property of a bank. Contrast that with this:

> I met a customer of a Wall Street investment bank.

Clearly, "a Wall Street investment bank" has many thousands of customers, and the sentence discusses only one of them. A single customer cannot be thought of as a unique property, so "a" is required for the first mention of a customer.

Comment: Thanks, I get how "of" can make it describe a unique property. Also checking if I got the last sentence right, putting "a" for the first mention before "Wall street investment bank"?

Comment: Certainly we should use "a" for the first mention of a bank. My point in the last sentence was about the first mention of a customer.

Comment: Oh, okay. I guess "the" is more often used when describing a unique property than "a"

Answer (score 1):

You're right about the definition of "the".

The structure is: **["the" + noun1 + "of" + noun2]**.

In this structure, "*of [noun2]*" defines which [noun1] we're talking about, so in your example sentence, "*the*" points forward to the long prepositional phrase "*of a ... grown-ups*", which defines the specific "willingness" we're talking about.

The meaning of the sentence is: "*This major bank pays me a lot of money to give investment advice to grown-ups, and I don't understand why they are willing to do that.*"

Comment: Thank you, I guess "a" can't points forward like "the" does?

Comment: Also, What does "points forward" mean?

Comment: Pronouns generally "point back" to some noun that came before. "The" can sometimes "point forward" to a word or phrase that's coming later on that it requires.

Comment: Um I searched the meaning of "willing" on Merriam Webster, I wonder which one is right one for the meaning in context? 1: inclined or favorably disposed in mind : READY, 3: done, borne, or accepted by choice or without reluctance

Comment: You can ask this in a separate question if it's important to you

Comment: Thank, I will after maybe read more chapters haha